# What is the word for digressing from a topic to talk passionately about something?

Tags: word-choice, dictionaries

Basically when someone jumps to a kind of related topic and talks about it very passionately for a while. What is the word for that?

As in, "I hate to go on a -------- but I want to tell the group about how the themes in this book relate to modern topics."

Not tangent or digress.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Why are *tangent* and *digress* not acceptable? I assume you see these as close to the intended meaning, so it might help to explain why they don't work.

Comment: Today, that's a *rant*. Used to be a *tear*.

Comment: One common way to express this idea is by starting with "I don't mean to hijack the conversation, but ..."

Answer (score 2):

You are making an ***[aside:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/aside://)***

> a remark or story in a speech or text that is not part of the main subject.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

the content of the aside would be a ***[panegyric](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/panegyric)***

> a eulogistic oration or writing

(M-W)

Answer (score 0):

[***Orate***](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/orate) or [***oration***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/oration)

> I don't want to orate, but a man of your position has so much to lose; you can't afford to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to go on a tangent, but...

> **tangent**  NOUN
> 2 A completely different line of thought or action.
> [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/tangent)

Comment: Should be "go OFF on a tangent" or (much less often) "AT a tangent"